# Excel - Writing proper SUM formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I am supposed to sum up the total highlighted numbers and add the sum in the red marked cell beside the average number. I am using a basic `SUM` formula to add the cells. I have a couple thousand lines to do this with and I have to manually change the SUM formula to include the right ranges (as some have 4 numbers to add up, some have 3 and others have 2). Is there a way to write the formula so it SUMS all the numbers up until the Average line above it? So I can use the same formula throughout my sheet and not have to change it for every line?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a variable range within a `SUM` function, using  `INDEX` and `MATCH` to find the previous instance of `Average`.

Something like this - an array formula, so enter with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
=SUM(B3:INDEX(B$1:B3,IFERROR(MATCH(2,1/(A$1:A3="Average")),0)+1))
```

[image]

Comment: although to be honest, if the maximum number of ranges you have to sum is 4 and the minimum is 2, you could simplify the formula by just looking for a match in the previous 5 rows - there could always only be 1 instance of "Average"

Comment: No unfortunately its random just used those numbers for the question. Also when I copy the formula it keeps the ranges from the previous one so I'm still have to edit the formula each time.

Comment: It should be a dynamic range - make sure that the first argument of index has a mixed reference - like (B$1:B3). The range will change when you copy, i.e (B$1:B7), (B$1:B12), (B$1:B17) in the screenshot.

Comment: Still seems to keep the first ranges

Comment: What's the exact formula you're using? What is the first row with data?

Comment: =SUM(G1499:INDEX(G$1497:G1499,IFERROR(MATCH(2,1/(F$1497:F1499="Average")),0)+1))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180471/discussion-between-bigben-and-cameron-cole).

Answer (score 2):

No need for Array formulas.

I will assume you are starting in H2. As per your photo in the discussion

```
=IF(E2 = "Average",SUMIF($E$1:E1,"<>Average",$G$1:G1)-SUM($H$1:H1),"")
```

And copy down.

[image]